# I'm looking for a formal definition of 'scintillations' in laser beam propagation

Tags: laser, structural-beam

I'm trying to make a scintillometer, based on Rytov's method. I've understood the whole phenomenon, and gone through some of the research papers in the field. But, I haven't encountered any definition as such. I was wondering whether there is any formal definition available.

Comment: I'm not sure, I understand your question but here is the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scintillometer) page for scintillations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SCINTILLATION:**

$\bullet$ The evaluation of the intensity fluctuations of the transmitted signals of a scintillometer.

$\bullet$ A rapid apparent displacement of a target indication from its mean position on a radar display; one cause is shifting of the effective reflection point on the target.
*(I myself don't like this second one though)*

$\bullet$ A brief ($\approx 10^{–4} \to 10^{–9}\text{sec}$) flash of light that occurs in a scintillator under the action of ionizing radiation.

A link which you may find useful:
[scintillation](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Scintillation+(disambiguation))

Please let me know if it was helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: @fluencyrequired please select it as answer if you feel it's helpful...